# Specific Formatting for an array

Tags: c++

I am given a text file called blabla.txt with the following formatting:

```
1
2 3
4 5 6
```

What code could I write to format this such that it looks like the following with commas and new lines as follows:

```
1, 
2, 3,
4, 5, 6
```

Comment: Can you show us what you tried?

Comment: so what is your doubt??

Comment: How do I modify the text file to include the commas

Comment: So is your question as how to add commas after each entry?

Comment: Yes to Jackz comment; there are also new lines in the original file that I'd like to preserve

Comment: It seems like just a matter of replacing spaces with a comma and a space and replacing all new lines with a comma and a new line (except for the last line).

Comment: Why don't you just take an editor? It would be faster than asking here, for those three lines at least. If you really want to write a program, pick up a basic C++ tutorial, they teach things like reading and writing files there, and also manipulating strings in between. I for one am not going to do your homework though.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Because it is his homework or something ;) He will be manager one day...

Comment: Try google and look for keywords like fopen() fread() fwrite() etc. Then read the online documentation on one of the 50000 sites. Or if you are masochistic, you can also use iostreams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your homework ;)

```
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <stdio.h>


int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    FILE * f = fopen("E:\\temp\\crap.txt", "wt");
    const char *t = "1\n2 3\n4 5 6 ";
    fwrite(t,1,strlen(t),f);
    fclose(f);

    f = fopen("E:\\temp\\crap.txt", "r+t");
    fseek(f, 0L, SEEK_END);
    size_t fs = ftell(f);
    fseek(f, 0L, SEEK_SET);
    std::string input;
    input.resize(fs);
    fread(&input[0], 1, fs, f);
    std::string output;
    output.reserve(2 * input.length());
    bool inText = false;
    for (auto c : input)
    {
        if (!isspace(c)) inText = true;
        else 
        {
            if (inText)
                output.push_back(',');
            inText = false;
        }
        output.push_back(c);
    }

    fseek(f, 0L, SEEK_SET);
    fwrite(output.data(), 1, output.length(), f);
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled and executed on FreeBsd (nearly mac ;) ) with clang this program produces:

```
more crap.txt
1,
2, 3,
4, 5, 6,
```

The same output was yielded on windows.

Comment: How do I replace the _TCHAR for mac? I am currently looking through this issue as we speak

Comment: you simply write the normal ``int main( int argc, const char *argv[] )`` version of main on non-windows systems. And you remove the ``#include "stdafx.h"`` , too on systems without precompiled headers.

Comment: And as on MAC, clang is used and this program uses c++11 features (the for loop), you compile with ``clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ program.cpp``

Comment: XCode uses clang normally. If you want to get rid of the last comma, remove the last blank in the input file string.

Comment: Sorry - so I changed both of the path names as follows:
FILE * f = fopen("Users/user/Desktop/blabla.txt", "wt");

but am getting the following error: "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code = 1, address = 0x68)

Comment: Have no Mac, sorry. Works on 2 systems for me. Maybe someone else who owns a MAC can comment on that?

Comment: Thanks...any help is appreciated for this error, I will try to look it up and see if I can handle it

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int rows,i,j,k=0;
    cout<<"Enter number of rows: ";
    cin>>rows;
    for(i=1;i<=rows;i++)
    {
        for(j=1;j<=i;++j)
          cout<<k+j<<",";
        ++k;
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How would I implement this onto the text file?

Comment: you want to print output put to the text file??

Comment: Ideally it would either modify the original text file or it could create a new text file

Comment: So, if there is a blabla.txt file as in the original - there would be code that would turn blabla.txt into the desired format w the commas (or it could possibly output it into another text file)

Comment: if you dont want to modify existing file, use: ofstream fout("filename.txt", ios::app);

Answer (score -1):

If I understood your point correctly then below is your solution.

public void Text(string text)
    {
        string line;
        int counter = 0;
        string newline = string.Empty;
        System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"E:\BlahBlah.txt");
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {

```
        var words = line.Split(' ');
        if (words.Count() > 1)
        {
            foreach (var word in words)
            {
                newline += word + ", ";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            newline = line + ", ";
        }

        counter++;
    }
    newline = newline.Trim(' ').Trim(',');

    Response.Write(newline.ToString() + System.Environment.NewLine);
    file.Close();
}
```

Comment: What Java? this is c#.

Comment: C#? It isnt even tagged C#. Sorry for the "Java" remark. :P

Comment: Now you are right :), but i guess he can get idea, c++ and c# relate to this point.

Comment: Relating is all right, but here at SO you are supposed to give a *to-the-point* answer, otherwise be ready for a shower of downvotes!